# Wordpress - Stopping redirect for category page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am listing out all of posts on the post page. Also the categories are listed in a sidebar. For some reason some links are redirecting to a post page. Can someone explain why this might be happening? The .htaccess file is the default that comes with wordpress as well. I am stumped. Also, my permalinks look like this `/weekly-insights/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`. I have tried refreshing my permalinks as well. If anyone could help me out where I am going wrong it would be appreciated. Again, I am just trying to click a category link and have it go to that particular page.

Comment: Have you refreshed the site permalink from the backend from Settings->permalink?

Comment: Yes. No matter how I change the permalinks and refresh it still occurs.